# r fortify in ggplot and tidy in broom package not accepting regions

Tags: r, ggplot2, broom

I can't get either ggplot's fortify or broom's tidy to include regions, even if I load the maptools library as suggested in another post.

I start by loading a bunch of libraries, including maptools (0.8-41), rgeos (0.3-22), broom (0.4.1) and ggplot2 (2.2.1.9000). Next I grab a map of the world that has a range of different region choices, including the one I'm interested in - ISO_a3 - with the following command.

```
world <- readOGR(dsn="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvkelso/natural-earth-vector/master/geojson/ne_50m_admin_0_countries.geojson", layer="OGRGeoJSON")
```

Next I run `map <- broom::tidy(world, region = "iso_a3")`

head(map) generates the following. Note that no region column is included.

```
      long       lat order  hole piece group  id
1 48.93857 11.258447     1 FALSE     1 -99.1 -99
2 48.93848 10.982324     2 FALSE     1 -99.1 -99
3 48.93848 10.714209     3 FALSE     1 -99.1 -99
4 48.93838 10.433252     4 FALSE     1 -99.1 -99
5 48.93828  9.973486     5 FALSE     1 -99.1 -99
6 48.93828  9.807617     6 FALSE     1 -99.1 -99
```

Comment: Your github link (in the readOGR) is broken.

Comment: The file can be downloaded at `https://github.com/nvkelso/natural-earth-vector/blob/master/geojson/ne_50m_admin_0_countries.geojson.gz` and the command changed to `world <- readOGR(dsn = "xxx/ne_50m_admin_0_countries.geojson", layer = "OGRGeoJSON")` where xxx is the path to the direction where the file is located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik, `fortify` and `tidy` do not append a column with the same name. See also the example

```
if (require("maptools")) {
 sids <- system.file("shapes/sids.shp", package="maptools")
 nc1 <- readShapePoly(sids,
   proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=NAD27"))
 nc1_df <- fortify(nc1)
}
head(nc1_df)
```

You are probably looking for the `id` column, which contains the `iso_a3`s:

```
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)
fn <- file.path(tempdir(), "ne_50m_admin_0_countries.geojson.gz")
download.file("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvkelso/natural-earth-vector/master/geojson/ne_50m_admin_0_countries.geojson.gz", fn)
R.utils::gunzip(fn)
world <- readOGR(dsn = tools::file_path_sans_ext(fn), layer = "OGRGeoJSON")
map <- broom::tidy(world, region="iso_a3")

all(sort(unique(map$id))==sort(levels(world$iso_a3)))
# [1] TRUE

ggplot(map, aes(long, lat, group=group)) + 
  geom_polygon(color="white") + 
  coord_quickmap()
```

Comment: Doh! (with sound of head slapping!)